# axapta random crashes multiple calls same method

Tags: static, axapta

I have a web application that makes calls to axapta, if I test the web with only one user, then evething goes perfectly. But, if I test the web with two or three users at the same time, and make calls with all the users to the same ax method (I have not tested diferent methods), then ax randomly crashes and even return diferents exceptions, BusinessConnectionException it's the most usual, but event so, the Message of the exception varies from error to error.

How can I detect the errors?
How can I get more info of what is wrong?
How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

This event crashes IIS somtimes...

**EDIT:**

see coments for solution explanation until I can answer my own.. "silly" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault all along... I have created the axapta client as a Singleton (static), and all the clients (I did not think about that) shared the same connection with ax. When I changed the static for a non static, then all worked, a little bit slower, but worked.